# Return rows only if count of them is bigger than 10

Tags: sql, postgresql, mybatis

I have two requests:

```
select count(*) <![CDATA[ > ]]> #{count} from bundle where updated_at <![CDATA[ > ]]> #{updatedAt}
select * from bundle where updated_at <![CDATA[ > ]]> #{updatedAt}
```

First I check if count of required records is bigger than I set. If it's true, then I'll get the records. Is it possible to combine the requests into one, returning rows only if count is bigger?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  How is the required count determined?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it comes from a java method

Comment: There's no need to escape `>` as `<![CDATA[ > ]]>`. For `<` though, you can type `&lt;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way is :

```
select * from (
select * , count(*) over () cc
from bundle where updated_at <![CDATA[ > ]]> #{updatedAt}
) tt
where cc > 10 --[your count limit]
```

or

```
select * from bundle where updated_at <![CDATA[ > ]]> #{updatedAt}
where (select count(*) from  bundle where updated_at <![CDATA[ > ]]> #{updatedAt}) > 10 --[your count limit]
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `>` as `<![CDATA[ > ]]>`.